# Cannot ping localhost but can access through browser

Tags: ip, localhost, wamp, virtualhost, ping

I am using wamp on my Win 7 laptop. 
`localhost` and `127.0.0.1` is accessible from the browser (Chrome) but when I'm try to run `ping localhost` or `ping 127.0.0.1` from the command prompt, I'm getting timeout.

[image]

I have a few virtual hosts created at `wamp` too, and I've added them to `hosts` file, and they too are accessible from browser but ping fails from `cmd`.

Also, running `ipconfig` doesn't show anything about the `wamp localhost`. The other `ips` that I get at `ipconfig` are getting pinged. Lastly, I cannot access my `localhost` using the `ip` on other devices connected to Laptop `wifi hotspot` created by `mHotspot`.

Someone please explain this behaviour to me, and help me access my localhost from my other devices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your TCP stack is in some way corrupted.

This may clear the issue

Open a command prompt as Administrator and Run

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Reboot if necessary

Try ping again